# Hosting two website on GoDaddy Windows Virtual Private Hosting

Tags: windows, dns, vps, hosting, godaddy

I have my Windows VPS hosting from godaddy and have my website on it. The website is http://www.Qlyer.com.

I wanted to host another website/domain on the same server and I did that using Parallels Plesk Panel and change the DNS A record from my godaddy account. The new website /domain I am trying to host is http://www.adollarapps.com

Now the problem is, this website is rendering the same website as Qlyer. How can I resolve this problem? Is it even possible to host multiple website on one VPS hosting account?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible. First you should check whether you have created the domain correctly on control panel? And the could you please make sure that you have point your domain (http://www.adollarapps.com) to correct IP Address?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! The answer does not look very useful. You should describe what do you mean by: *check whether you have created the domain correctly on control panel*.